# Connecting Flex with database for Facebook apps

Tags: flash, apache-flex, facebook, air

I have a task to make simple game that deployed as a facebook app using Adobe Flex.
Like most facebook game, I need to show high score, compare score with friends and some other similar functionalities, which I think need some sort of database thing.

The problem is a had only little experience about database, only have tried simple things with MySQL and I don't know where to start.

Anyone have suggestions on how to do this in simple way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to quantify the amount of data you need to be stored in the database. I would suggest using a service layer to access your database. Flex is not optimized for database interaction.

If the data is not of very high volume  and is not very critical, then you can use sql lite. Its probably the easiest solution. But if you have considerable data, then  I would suggest leveraging services like Google App Engine to provide you with a database.